# Elasticsearch learning roadmap

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, search-engine

I have to set up Elasticsearch search engine in my job website enterprise. We've choosen this solution becasue it's scalable powerfull and personalizable. As a beginner of ES, I've only set up basic functionnalities such as simple research on a test website, but nothing to complex. My goal is to implement step by step more complicated functionnalities like synonyms, multilingual results, filters... And so on.

I would like to know if you had to implement something like this, and if you have any tips and tricks about bests practices. Also note that I've already red a lot about ElasticSearch but there's so many content that any "roadmap" or learning resources is welcome.

I'll be happy to read your advices and experiences with this amazing tool, best regards.

Comment: what have you done so far in the field of synonyms / filters etc? have you tried starting with ES docs on those subjects? what are your main use cases? how do you plan to store your data (on ES?), do you plan to use the full ELK stack? (Kibana, logstash) ? i'd start defining smaller tasks, and adding more info to this question to be more use-case oriented.

Comment: I didn"t implement synonyms and filters yet, I've simply red the docs because I have side projects at my office and can't spend all my time on ES, but so far, I've made a symple search bar and started using fuzzy requests. I'm planning to test synonyms during this month and maybe filter if i have more time. I'll be using ELK stack for sure because we need to see statistics based on user's researches :) thank you for your response

Comment: let's try to define a smaller use case for this question - what do we want to solve/do now?

Comment: Basically, we want to improve our search system on our website. The main goal is to reduce zero responses queries by making synonyms filters, auto-suggestions, fuzzy requests. We want our system to be fast for customers. Actually, search bar on our website is really simple, it does the searching into a database and return results if not empty.